# how to get whole html or json repsonse of an URL using Newman API

Tags: api, postman, newman

Whenever I run following from command line

```
newman run https://www.getpostman.com/collections/abcd1234
```

I get output displaying the statistics of failed and execute.

But I am looking for the complete HTML or JSON response from the URL to be printed on terminal after executing the above Newman query.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some log output in your requests.

For the requests where you want to see the response output add the following in the Postman Tests tab:

```
console.log(responseBody); // full response body
```

If you want to log a specific part you have to parse the response body into a JSON object:

```
let response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(reponse.myprop); // part of the full response body
```

Now if you run this collection with newman the CLI reporter will print the console log parts as well.

Comment: hello, I am getting `ReferenceError: responseBody is not defined` is this because i am loading a collection locally, not with a url?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Postman API.

So you need to run something like this

```
newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/myPostmanCollectionUid?apikey=myPostmanApiKey
```

(see http://blog.getpostman.com/2018/06/21/newman-run-and-test-your-collections-from-the-command-line/)
You can get ApiKey in your Postman Cloud. You need to go to the workspace -> Integrations -> Browse Integrations -> Postman API View details -> Detail Get API Key/Existing API Keys

If you also need to add environment (if you use Variables), what you need is to run the same command with -e parameter 'newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/myPostmanCollectionUid?apikey=myPostmanApiKey -e dev_environment.json'

But what if you have your environment in the cloud as well? According to this document https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman you can pass URL as value. So you may run something like this

```
newman run https://api.getpostman.com/collections/myPostmanCollectionUid?apikey=myPostmanApiKey -e environments/{{environment_uid}}?apikey=myPostmanApiKey
```

It worked for me, hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I am using newman for webservices and microservices testing. This works fine for me.

```
summary.run.executions[0].response.text().toString()
```

After done event you should be able to get the response.

d is the collection exported from Postman.

```
newman.run({
            collection: d,
            // reporters: 'cli',
            iterationCount: 1,
            timeoutRequest: 10000,
            timeoutScript: 5000,
            delayRequest: 0,
            insecure: false, 
        }).on('done', (err, summary) => {
            if (err || summary.error) {
                console.error('\ncollection run encountered an error.');
                reject(summary.error);
            }
            else {
                var xml = summary.run.executions[0].response.text().toString();
                console.log(xml)
            }
        })
    })
```